# increment a value in iteration in java stringtemplate

Tags: java, antlr3, stringtemplate

I have my array as below in java string template:

```
$colors:{ color |
<p>$color.name$
}$
```

Output is :

```
Green
Black
```

The output is want is:

```
1. Green
2. Black
```

How do I achieve this? How to get the incremented counter in antlr.stringtemplate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use built-in attribute `$i$` to start enumeration from one, or `$i0$` - from zero.

```
$colors:{ color |
<p>$i$.&nbsp;$color.name$
}$
```

Please, also see [another example usage](https://github.com/antlr/stringtemplate3/blob/e60b23544539d64d2f57a87e87a5b383cc2b0ba9/test/org/antlr/stringtemplate/test/TestStringTemplate.java#L1424) in ST3 GIT repo.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is more an HTML issue.

```
<ol>$colors:{ color |
<li>$color.name$</li>
}$
</ol>
```

The output:

```
<ol>
<li>Green</li>
<li>Black</li>
</ol>
```

As viewed:

1. Green
2. Black

In general numbering (i. ii. iii. iv. e.a.) and such can be done with CSS styles, or even JavaScript in HTML.